# Automatically format 1000 identical csv files to import into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have about 1000 csv files that hold client information, they're all formatted the same way.  I'm trying to move all of these files into a MySQL Database table, either all on one table, or one table per csv, whichever is more plausable.

Anyways, all I can find is information on doing it with a couple csv files, manually going into them and formatting them correctly, then importing into MySQL.  There's no way I can do that with over 1000 files.

---

Files came from google spreadsheets, the original hoster for the companys clients (each having their own spreadsheet for their data).

Moving over to an application I've built for the company.

Comment: Write a program that cycles through a directory in which all of the CSV files reside. Load one, reformat it programatically, insert into database. Rinse, lather, repeat.

Comment: i wrote a script for it literally a minute ago... I can write a general version of this script and post it here, or you can play with this function `$files=glob('*.csv');` and let me know if you still need help.

Comment: will post general answer in a couple minutes.

Comment: @Dimi do not answer overly broad questions, especially those where the OP has shown no effort.

Comment: Are you kidding?  It's not broad, they're csv files that hold the same columns and rows as the tables they're going into, and I wouldn't have any idea on how to cycle through files and change their format.  If not knowing how to do something at all, because it's outside of your specialty, is equal to no effort than I guess I'm guilty

Comment: It's totally broad. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We don't know what your environment looks like, we have no idea how the original CSV files are formatted and therefore can only give you general information as I did in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general version of my CSV importer. 
Create a table and replace 'your_table_name_here' with your table. Create all the columns and run this script in the folder that has all of your CSV files. It will do its best to match all columns with the data.

```
//Create database connection


$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'your_database';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);



//Run this script in the folder that has all the CSV files that you want to import


//Grab list of all CSV files
$files=glob('*.csv');


foreach($files as $file)
{

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $cnt = 0;
    $is_first = true;
    echo "OPENING $file\n";

    if($handle)
        //Change this value. Usually delimiter is ',' but if your CSV file has something else, you will need to modify this value
        $delimiter='|';

    while (($csv = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, $delimiter)) !== false) {

        $d = array();

        if ($is_first) {
            $is_first = false;
            $header=$csv;

            $inserter=$pdo->prepare("replace into your_table_name_here(`".implode('`,`',$header)."`)
                values (:".implode(',:',$header).");");
        }
        else {
            $to_insert=array();
            foreach($csv as $key=>$val)
            {
                $to_insert[':'.$header[$key]]=$val;
            }
            $inserter->execute($to_insert);
        }
    }
}
```